# Why is Git rejecting my pull simply because I have a commit on my local branch?

Tags: git

There is a Git repository on a server that my colleague and I both push to and pull from. It works fine as long as we pull before committing.

However, if he has pushed to the master branch, and in the mean time I have made a local commit, when I try to pull I get this:

```
! [rejected]        master    -> master  (non-fast-forward)
```

But I know that there should be no conflict.

The way I get around it is by pulling into a new temporary branch and then merging that into my master like this:

```
% git pull origin master:temp
From ssh://example.com/home/my/remote/repo
 * [new branch]      master    -> temp
Already up-to-date.
% git merge temp
Already up-to-date.
% git push origin master:master
```

Notice that Git acts like I'm not doing anything, but really I have shaken it into submission.

Recently I realized that instead of trying to to "convince" Git that it's OK for me to pull. I can just pretend that I haven't committed yet with `git reset --soft HEAD^` and `git stash` and then do the pull and commit on top of that.

What might be causing this strangely finicky behavior?

I was able to reproduce this problem all on my local machine. Here's what I did:

First I made the first "local" repository and added a file.

```
% cd
% mkdir local-1
% cd local-1/
% mkdir website
% cd website/
% git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/jason/local-1/website/.git/
% touch file
% git add .
% git commit -m 'added file'
[master (root-commit) 6d4b322] added file
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file
```

Then I made the "remote" repository.

```
% cd
% mkdir remote
% cd remote
% mkdir website.git
% cd website.git/
% git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/jason/remote/website.git/
```

Then I went back to the local, created a ref and pushed to the remote.

```
% cd ~/local-1/website/
% git remote add web ~/remote/website.git
% git push web +master:refs/heads/master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 207 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
To /Users/jason/remote/website.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

After that I cloned the remote into a second local.

```
% cd
% mkdir local-2
% cd local-2
% git clone ~/remote/website.git
Cloning into website...
done.
```

Then I created a ref to the remote from the second local and pushed (this is where I am creating the problem I think).

```
% cd website/
% git remote add web ~/remote/website.git
% git push web +master:refs/heads/master
Everything up-to-date
```

Then I made a change to local-2, committed, and pushed.

```
% touch another
% git add .
% git commit -m 'added another'
[master be91180] added another
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 another
% git push web
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 238 bytes, done.
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (2/2), done.
To /Users/jason/remote/website.git
   6d4b322..be91180  master -> master
```

Finally, I made a different change to local-1, committed, and tried to push.

```
% cd ~/local-1/website/
% touch something
% git add .
% git commit -m 'added something'
[master 3984529] added something
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 something
% git push web
To /Users/jason/remote/website.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to '/Users/jason/remote/website.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Blast! How about a pull?

```
% git pull web master:master
From /Users/jason/remote/website
 ! [rejected]        master     -> master  (non-fast-forward)
```

OK, so there's the problem. How do I fix it?

Comment: The behavior you describe at the beginning is definitely not normal. (It has nothing to do with merge conflicts, though.) Do you have anything at all unusual in `.git/config` or `~/.gitconfig`? If you're not sure, either comment it all out and test, or post the whole thing. (Setting something for `pull.twohead` could cause this, I suppose...) Have you managed to create any weird refs? Run `gitk --all` and inspect, or more rigorous, run `git for-each-ref`. If there's anything called master that's not `refs/heads/master` or `refs/remotes/origin/master`, that could be a problem.

Comment: I have seen "best practices" advice that suggests aliasing `pull` to `pull --ff-only`, which would cause the situation you are describing. I would check for that in particular.

Comment: @Clueless: Ah, yeah, I checked to see if there was a `pull.ff-only` config option but I didn't think about that. Seems like a good guess!

Comment: @Jefromi, there's nothing strange in my config, but I did find something in the history with gitk. I started the first repo on my local machine and used 'web' as the name of the remote. when my colleague cloned the repo from the server I put it on, he added the ref for 'web' without deleting the default ref of 'origin'. What I found in my repo (which has always called the remote by 'web') in fact has an old commit that that says `remotes/origin/master`. Is this the problem? How could I clean it out?

Comment: I think you need to take another look at your config. Which remote is `master` pulling from? Is pull aliased to anything? (A stale remote branch is not a problem, but you can remove it with `git branch -r -d origin/master`.)

Comment: @Jefromi my git config is [here](http://pastebin.com/q6zRb1Hv) and my colleague's is [here](http://pastebin.com/dPYj1KP4). I had him take out the three lines starting with `[remote "origin"]` and it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Okay. Is there anything in `~/.gitconfig` though? Do you have any shell aliases? Basically, either you've hit a severe bug that I've never seen or heard of before (seems unlikely) or you've got something configured funny somehow.

Comment: nothing in ~/.gitconfig except my name and email. I'll try starting over with a new repository and see if I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: What happens if you split the pull in fetch and merge? BTW, this would also make your workaround easier, because you won't have to setup a temporary branch manually.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You probably meant to do:

```
git pull web master
```

Using `master:master` is trying to directly update you local `master` branch in the fetch stage of the pull which is causing the non fast-forward error.

If you're on a branch that is set up to track `web/master` then you only need `git pull web` and this will update your remote tracking branches as well.

Comment: awesome. so simple for such an embarrassingly long question!

Comment: I got the exact same issue when I tried to pull my Heroku endpoint's master branch into local develop.

Comment: I am having the same issue. But instead i make `git pull origin trunk:master` because i use `git-svn` to fetch changes. So this just can't fix that.